# Unable to make a new column in Pandas dataframe from two existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Here, I'm trying to create a new column 'new' from the sum of two columns using .loc, but I'm unable to create it, it throws an error saying 'W' in invalid key.

> This works

```
df['new'] = df['W'] + df['Y']
```

> This is not working

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1.0,5.0,1],[2,np.NaN,2],[np.NaN,np.NaN,3]], columns = ['W','Y','Z'])
df['new'] = df.loc['W'] + df.loc['Y']
```

Comment: `loc` works on indices first, and (if given) columns after. Take a look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for more examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass two arguments to loc - row and column. So in your case it will be:

```
df['new'] = df.loc[:, 'W'] + df.loc[:, 'Y']
```